# exec hello.pl file in php by sending variable

Tags: php, perl, exec

I have a file hello.pl and i want to call in php. I used exec(perl perl_tests\hello.pl) and I

want to send variables in to this pl file can you give me advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec('perl perl_tests\hello.pl arg1 arg2 arg3 ....')` will do the trick.

After a minute of googling: http://www.ryerson.ca/perl/runningAScript.html. There is a command line entry at the bottom.

Comment: $_POST['metin'];
$result=exec('perl perl_tests\hello.pl', metin);
echo $result;
and im getting fatality error

Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\deneme.ph

Comment: is `metin` a string or variable?

Comment: it is variable im getting this variable form form 
<input type=text name=metin>

Comment: Then `exec('perl perl_tests\hello.pl '.$metin)` should work. Note that you should ensure `$metin` is escaped for the console.

Comment: what do you mean it should be escaped . i think thats why i m getting undefined error thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Function `exec()` simply runs console command. So to call your script with parameters just put inside this function a string which you run in command line.